# Azure web app not passing https scheme to java web application

Tags: java, azure, iis, ssl, azure-web-app-service

I am trying to enforce https on an Azure java web app running on tomcat 1.7. (The application wa created using the portal)
I have added the below  web.config to the site/wwwroot directory.  This is correctly redirecting the non http calls via https, but inside the application the request appears to have a http rather than https.

```
<configuration>
<system.webServer>
<handlers>
  <add name="httpPlatformHandler" path="*"
       verb="*" modules="httpPlatformHandler"
       resourceType="Unspecified" />
</handlers>

<httpPlatform processPath="%AZURE_TOMCAT7_HOME%\bin\startup.bat">
</httpPlatform>
<rewrite>
  <rules>
    <rule name="Force HTTPS" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="(.*)" ignoreCase="false" />
      <conditions>
        <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="off" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}/{R:1}" appendQueryString="true" redirectType="Permanent" />
    </rule>
  </rules>
</rewrite>
</system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

I think it might be standard behavior for the application to be showing http rather than https, but i was certainly expecting the below to render true

```
HttpServletRequest request
request.isSecure()  //this should be true
request.getScheme() //Ideally should be https but is http
```

Is there anything I need to add to my web.config file?

not sure if it makes much difference but I am using CA signed wild card certificate which I have also uploaded through portal.  This is definately working becasue before I couldnt make https calls on my web app and after the certificate upload I was able to make the calls.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: What happens when you make an https request to your site? Does the request still appear to be http inside your application?

Comment: No even if I hit it directly it is http inside the application and still shows false when I call isSecure ()

Comment: Does https load properly if you run the site on your local machine?

Comment: if i set the tomcat connector  secure  attribute to true this is definately passed through locally. The problem is how to get this set on Azure web apps becasue we dont have direct access to the tomcat instance

Comment: If you have access to the tomcat configuration, then adding secure="true" and scheme="https" to the tomcat connector works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to answer the problem domain of editing configuration, there are 3 methods of using Java with Azure App Service:

1) enable through the portal.  This method is great when uploading a war file but you cannot change configuration for the web container.

2) deploy Tomcat or Jetty from the Marketplace/gallery.  When you do this you get a complete install of Tomcat or Jetty in your space that you can edit or alter to your hearts content

3) upload a custom app including your own jvm if desired.  If you go this route there are a few things you need to keep in mind that are described in the Azure documentation.

With respect to SSL, due to the need in App Service to support a multitude of frameworks, SSL is supported upstream of the app.  You don't need to enable the HTTPS connector in Tomcat or locally set a trust store or any of those fun things.  Use the information here: http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-configure-ssl-certificate/ to enable HTTPS for your site.

Comment: I figured this was the case.  Unfortunately for me I have 20 sites deployed so it's going to be quite a task.  thanks for you help